# Time Series data to be analysed

Tags: r

I am new to r.  So please bear with me.

I have a employee log data available with me.  The number of lines that I have is close to 1.2 Million (I have more data point for the same time series so want to try something first then I can deep dive with more data points).  I want to analysis the data.

The log contains details of when a person whet to floor and come out.  I want to display the same as a graph.

Note: I want to showcase the entire population data such that it becomes a running chart were Employee Name and Date are the rows and column header will be the time and the data that will come up needs to be color coded.  Like if a given employee is on the floor from 2:00 PM to 2:30 PM I will color code it as green etc.

> Event Desc's Anti-Pass-Back Fault on Entry - Swiped in more than once 
>   Anti-Pass-Back Fault on Exit - Swiped out more than once Entry granted
>   - Regular Entry Exit granted - Regular Exit

Attaching sample data for your reference.

```
Date,Event Description,Reader Name,Card No,Emp Name,Site,Emp ID
3/2/2015 8:21:01,Entry granted,Door1,2,A1,ABC,Emp2
3/2/2015 8:28:57,Exit granted,Door1,2,A1,ABC,Emp2
3/2/2015 8:33:51,Entry granted,Door1,2,A1,ABC,Emp2
3/2/2015 8:46:24,Exit granted,Door1,2,A1,ABC,Emp2
3/2/2015 8:56:15,Entry granted,Door1,2,A1,ABC,Emp2
3/2/2015 10:02:46,Exit granted,Door1,2,A1,ABC,Emp2
3/2/2015 10:09:44,Entry granted,Door1,2,A1,ABC,Emp2
3/2/2015 11:12:48,Exit granted,Door1,2,A1,ABC,Emp2
3/2/2015 11:16:22,Entry granted,Door1,2,A1,ABC,Emp2
3/2/2015 11:21:47,Exit granted,Door1,2,A1,ABC,Emp2
3/2/2015 11:22:58,Entry granted,Door1,2,A1,ABC,Emp2
3/2/2015 12:07:22,Exit granted,Door1,2,A1,ABC,Emp2
3/2/2015 12:22:07,Entry granted,Door1,2,A1,ABC,Emp2
3/2/2015 13:12:44,Exit granted,Door1,2,A1,ABC,Emp2
3/2/2015 13:16:02,Entry granted,Door1,2,A1,ABC,Emp2
3/2/2015 14:00:33,Exit granted,Door1,2,A1,ABC,Emp2
3/2/2015 14:04:58,Entry granted,Door1,2,A1,ABC,Emp2
3/2/2015 14:08:19,Exit granted,Door1,2,A1,ABC,Emp2
3/3/2015 9:02:47,Entry granted,Door1,2,A1,ABC,Emp2
3/3/2015 9:05:27,Exit granted,Door1,2,A1,ABC,Emp2
3/3/2015 9:11:42,Entry granted,Door1,2,A1,ABC,Emp2
3/3/2015 10:44:58,Exit granted,Door1,2,A1,ABC,Emp2
3/3/2015 10:50:03,Entry granted,Door1,2,A1,ABC,Emp2
3/3/2015 10:54:22,Exit granted,Door1,2,A1,ABC,Emp2
3/3/2015 10:58:14,Entry granted,Door1,2,A1,ABC,Emp2
3/3/2015 12:12:04,Exit granted,Door1,2,A1,ABC,Emp2
3/3/2015 12:27:54,Entry granted,Door1,2,A1,ABC,Emp2
3/3/2015 13:00:29,Exit granted,Door1,2,A1,ABC,Emp2
3/3/2015 13:04:33,Entry granted,Door1,2,A1,ABC,Emp2
3/3/2015 13:06:04,Exit granted,Door1,2,A1,ABC,Emp2
3/3/2015 13:29:33,Entry granted,Door1,2,A1,ABC,Emp2
3/3/2015 14:27:52,Exit granted,Door1,2,A1,ABC,Emp2
3/3/2015 14:32:55,Entry granted,Door1,2,A1,ABC,Emp2
3/3/2015 16:12:11,Exit granted,Door1,2,A1,ABC,Emp2
3/3/2015 16:15:35,Entry granted,Door1,2,A1,ABC,Emp2
3/3/2015 17:06:40,Exit granted,Door1,2,A1,ABC,Emp2
3/3/2015 17:12:18,Entry granted,Door1,2,A1,ABC,Emp2
3/3/2015 17:55:42,Exit granted,Door1,2,A1,ABC,Emp2
3/3/2015 18:00:20,Entry granted,Door1,2,A1,ABC,Emp2
3/3/2015 18:46:23,Exit granted,Door1,2,A1,ABC,Emp2
3/4/2015 8:43:38,Entry granted,Door1,2,A1,ABC,Emp2
3/4/2015 8:48:14,Exit granted,Door1,2,A1,ABC,Emp2
3/4/2015 9:00:45,Entry granted,Door1,2,A1,ABC,Emp2
3/4/2015 9:49:05,Exit granted,Door1,2,A1,ABC,Emp2
3/4/2015 9:53:15,Entry granted,Door1,2,A1,ABC,Emp2
3/4/2015 10:05:51,Exit granted,Door1,2,A1,ABC,Emp2
3/4/2015 10:14:14,Entry granted,Door1,2,A1,ABC,Emp2
3/4/2015 11:16:32,Exit granted,Door1,2,A1,ABC,Emp2
3/4/2015 11:39:11,Entry granted,Door1,2,A1,ABC,Emp2
3/4/2015 11:40:08,Exit granted,Door1,2,A1,ABC,Emp2
3/4/2015 11:44:29,Entry granted,Door1,2,A1,ABC,Emp2
3/4/2015 12:51:01,Exit granted,Door1,2,A1,ABC,Emp2
3/4/2015 12:56:30,Entry granted,Door1,2,A1,ABC,Emp2
```

copied from CSV file.

Comment: What have you already tried? Why did it not work? Can you give an example of your wanted output?

Comment: I think the question can be solved using [reshape2](http://seananderson.ca/2013/10/19/reshape.html) basically you need to cast your "long" frame to a "wide" one.  btw the example you provide is not helpful as it only has employee 2 and it would also help if you show the expected result - a sketch maybe.

Comment: I wish I could provide more data.  I am attaching the screen print of what is needed shortly.

Comment: Here is the link to the file on Google Drive.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bwnjks5ujo3kRUJQQmtUTWE0SGd2eEpEbk8weEs5VVhuTkZF/view?usp=docslist_api

Comment: You will see the Data tab that contains all the raw data.  the next two tabs are my workings to get the right format.  the last one is what I actually need from r.    The problem with Excel is that it will not be able to analysis 1.2 million records, even if i write a program for the same I have another 2 million records with more parameters.